# Getting JSP Exception in WAS 8.0 thrown by application class 'org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToNumber:364

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, el, websphere-liberty

I am getting this error that my `JSP` throws.
This works on `WebSphere 7.0` but fails in `Liberty profile  8.5`

```
    [ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToNumber:364'
javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert 34|5:00 PM  of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Long
    at org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToNumber(ELSupport.java:364)
    at [internal classes]
    at com.ibm._jsp._myCalAreaRole._jspx_meth_c_if_40(_myCalAreaRole.java:4286)
    at com.ibm._jsp._myCalAreaRole._jspx_meth_c_otherwise_1(_myCalAreaRole.java:4370)
    at com.ibm._jsp._myCalAreaRole._jspx_meth_c_choose_1(_myCalAreaRole.java:4413)
    at com.ibm._jsp._myCalAreaRole._jspx_meth_c_forEach_11(_myCalAreaRole.java:4457)
    at com.ibm._jsp._myCalAreaRole._jspx_meth_c_if_36(_myCalAreaRole.java:5502)
    at com.ibm._jsp._myCalAreaRole._jspx_meth_c_if_14(_myCalAreaRole.java:7663)
    at com.ibm._jsp._myCalAreaRole._jspx_meth_c_if_13(_myCalAreaRole.java:7763)
    at com.ibm._jsp._myCalAreaRole._jspx_meth_c_if_11(_myCalAreaRole.java:7814)
    at com.ibm._jsp._myCalAreaRole._jspx_meth_c_if_8(_myCalAreaRole.java:7864)
    at com.ibm._jsp._myCalAreaRole._jspService(_myCalAreaRole.java:374)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:101)
    at [internal classes]
    at com.ibm._jsp._myCalArea._jspx_meth_c_if_5(_myCalArea.java:1695)
    at com.ibm._jsp._myCalArea._jspx_meth_c_if_3(_myCalArea.java:1823)
    at com.ibm._jsp._myCalArea._jspService(_myCalArea.java:203)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:101)
    at [internal classes]
    at edu.mayo.MainController.goTo(MainController.java:1751)
    at edu.mayo.MainController.doGet(MainController.java:515)
    at edu.mayo.MainController.doPost(MainController.java:1745)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1290)
    at [internal classes]
```

I was able to look at the part of `JSP` that does all this.

```
<select name="StartTime${Cnt}">
          <c:forEach var="Periods" items="${Periods}">
                <c:set var="period_id" value="${Periods.period_id}"/>
                <c:if test='${period_id == RolePerson.starttime}'>
                <option value="${period_id}|${Periods.period_text}" selected>${Periods.period_text}</option>
                </c:if>       
           <c:if test='${period_id != RolePerson.starttime}'>
           <option value="${period_id}|${Periods.period_text}">${Periods.period_text}</option>
            </c:if>       
       </c:forEach>
       </select>
```

The HTML output looks like ..

```
<select name="StartTime2">
<option value="0|12:01 AM">12:01 AM</option>
<option value="1|12:30 AM">12:30 AM</option>
…
<option value="34|5:00 PM ">5:00 PM </option>
```

Seems the 34|5:00 PM is considered by the select option as a number and so it tries to parse it.

I also found the coerce method.. in the `EL` javax code online

```
protected final static Number coerceToNumber(final String val,
        final Class type) {
    if (Long.TYPE == type || Long.class.equals(type)) {
        return Long.valueOf(val);
    }
    if (Integer.TYPE == type || Integer.class.equals(type)) {
        return Integer.valueOf(val);
    }
    if (Double.TYPE == type || Double.class.equals(type)) {
        return Double.valueOf(val);
    }
    if (BigInteger.class.equals(type)) {
        return new BigInteger(val);
    }
    if (BigDecimal.class.equals(type)) {
        return new BigDecimal(val);
    }
    if (Byte.TYPE == type || Byte.class.equals(type)) {
        return Byte.valueOf(val);
    }
    if (Short.TYPE == type || Short.class.equals(type)) {
        return Short.valueOf(val);
    }
    if (Float.TYPE == type || Float.class.equals(type)) {
        return Float.valueOf(val);
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(MessageFactory.get("error.convert",
            val, String.class, type));
}
```

I see that select can have String values but seems this value starting with 34 is considered as an int /long or number and so it gets parsed as number and half through the parsing blows up because it is a String type.

Not sure but is there a way that we can force and let compiler know the value type is a String so it does not try auto detect ...

Thanks
Dhiren

Comment: I am not comparing these values against Long. This works in WAS 7.0 . What I  don't get is why server JSP compiler tries to auto detect this as Long or INT and run the internal EL JSP parser to Number whereas it is clearly a String.

Comment: You should probably raise a PMR in IBM Support.

Comment: I have the same problem! It works fine on WAS 8.5.5.0 and fails on Liberty, all versions of liberty, how you solve? @user2358826